# x86 assembly code confusion

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

We've just begun the topic on assembly and I've been stuck on this problem for the longest time.  I have to convert assembly to C code given the following:

C Code:

```
int foo(int *a, int n, int val) {
    int i;
    for (i = _________; ____________________________ ; i =___________) {
        ;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Assembly:

```
// what I've gathered so far
foo()
:
foo:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp,%ebp
movl 8(%ebp),%ecx  // ecx: a
movl 16(%ebp),%edx  // edx: val
movl 12(%ebp),%eax  // eax: n
decl %eax  // n = n--
js .L3  // if n < 0 goto done
.L7:  // loop
cmpl %edx,(%ecx,%eax,4)  // I don't understand how you would compute the
// address for (%ecx,%eax,4) I know it would be %ecx + %eax*4 = %ecx + eax << 2
jne .L3  // if (%ecx, %eax, 4) != val goto done (?)
decl %eax  // n = n--
jns .L7  // if (n >= 0) jump to loop
.L3:  // done
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

I don't know how to figure out what i is being initialized to and what the body of the loop is.  I'm assuming i = n since n serves as the update.  It seems as if there are two conditions one being n > 0 and the other being the cmpl line.  Please correct me if my understanding of the code is incorrect, and any clues to this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: It is looking for a value in an array, but I'm not going to write what is actually a rather simple loop for you. Be careful with the end conditions!.

Comment: *...what the body of the loop is*: in C, the loop can have no body. Based upon the form shown in your C pattern, that seems to be the case. All of the interesting work is being done in the initial condition (the first `__`), the test condition, (second `__`) and the "increment" statement (third `__`).

Comment: The compiler managed to use registers for all local variables in the function.  It is a simple loop and you almost got it right. The first and last expressions in the `for` statement are pretty simple, the condition expression tests for 2 conditions.  Also remember that `a` is a pointer to an array of `int`s.

Comment: Another clue: the way this loop is written is cumbersome.  You could simplify it to keep the same semantics, while removing the update (third) expression and making the compiled code shorter.

Comment: @chqrlie my guess is the posted C code is the required template for the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could have done some off-by 1 errors, but basically it is this:

```
int foo(int *a, int n, int val) {
    int i;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0 && a[i] == val; i = i - 1) {
        ;
    }
    return i;
}
```

The `i` is the `%eax` register; it loops from `n - 1` to 0. The `cmpl` indexed access `(%ecx,%eax,4)` is addressed in bytes - this is equivalent to `a[i]`, as size of `int` on ia32 is 4 bytes. The 4 bytes addressed thus is compared against `val`.

The `%eax` is implicitly returned.

Notice also, that `js` means `< 0`, and `jns` **`>= 0`**.

---

Another way to write it:

```
    i = n;
    i --;               //  decl %eax
    if (i < 0) {
        goto L3;        //  js .L3
    }
L7:
    if (a[i] != val)    // cmpl %edx,(%ecx,%eax,4)
        goto L3;        // jne .L3

    i --;               // decl %eax
    if (i >= 0)
        goto L7;        // jns .L7

L3:
    return i;
```

Comment: Isn't the line: cmpl %edx,(%ecx,%eax,4)
jne .L3 
saying that if a[i] != val, jump to L3 (which is the finish code)? Why would it continue in the for-loop?

Comment: of course the comments are a bit off there because the cmpl+jne together is the if

Comment: @AnttiHaapala commenters above were trying to be helpful without actually doing the homework. Downvote.

Comment: OP showed understanding of the assembly but was lost at how to translate it to C in this case - given that the topic was understanding assembly, then converting it to C is superficial at most.

Comment: Not exactly one off errors, but the variable name is wrong in the test expression. Use this: `for (i = n - 1; i >= 0 && a[i] == val; i = i - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using the preprocessor:

```
#define _________ n - 1
#define ____________________________  i >= 0 && a[i] == val
#define ___________  i + 1

int foo(int *a, int n, int val) {
    int i;
    for (i = _________; ____________________________ ; i =___________) {
        ;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Of course you can only use this for fun or to tease new programmers ;-)